# Image upload php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I am trying to upload 2 images and save the file name for each file to MySQL database. I have tried different options but I can't get this to work.

On my MYSQL table field name for file name is called file_name 
varchar 500

I can save the other form data into my database without a problem. 
However I can't get the image(s) uploaded.

Following is my image portion of the web form.

Here is the FORM action area

```
<form method="post" action="php/smartprocess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="smart-form">
```

My image upload section as following

smartprocess.php section is

```
 <?php 

if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); 
if(!$_POST) exit;

require 'database.php';

include dirname(__FILE__).'/settings/settings.php';
include dirname(__FILE__).'/functions/emailValidation.php';

$TechName = strip_tags(trim($_POST["TechName"]));
$FullAssembly = strip_tags(trim($_POST["FullAssembly"]));
$Notes = strip_tags(trim($_POST["Notes"]));
$SignedDate = strip_tags(trim($_POST["SignedDate"]));
$captcha = strip_tags(trim($_POST["captcha"]));




 try {

       $q = "INSERT INTO tportal (TechName, FullAssembly, Notes, SignedDate)

             VALUES (:TechName, :FullAssembly, :Notes, :SignedDate)";


                     $query = $conn -> prepare($q);

                     $results = $query -> execute(array(

                      ":TechName" => $TechName,
                      ":FullAssembly" => $FullAssembly,

                      ":Notes" => $Notes,
                      ":SignedDate" => $SignedDate,

                      ));

                      if ($conn->query($q)) {

                          $errors = array();

                      echo '<div class="alert notification alert-success">Problem has accured please try again.</div>';
                     //Javascript alert top
                     /*echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Issue adding data');</script>";*/

                     }
                     else{
                      echo '<div class="alert notification alert-success">Your message has been sent successfully!</div>';
                     //Javascript alert top
                     /*echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted. $PocketCond');</script>";*/

                     }

                      $conn = null;
                     }
                     catch(PDOException $e)
                     {
                     echo $e->getMessage();
                     }


                     ?>
                 <?php

                if(isset($_POST["captcha"])){
                if (!$captcha) {
                    $errors[] = "You must enter the captcha code";
                } else if (($captcha) != $_SESSION['gfm_captcha']) {
                $errors[] = "Captcha code is incorrect";
    }
}

?>



            <div class="section">
                    <label for="file1" class="field-label"> 
                        Upload another image - <span class="small-text   fine-grey"> (ONLY JPG : PNG : PDF) </span> 
                    </label>
                    <label class="field prepend-icon file">
                        <span class="button btn-primary"> Choose File </span>
                        <input type="file" class="gui-file" name="image"  id="file1" 
                        onChange="document.getElementById('uploader1').value = this.value;">
                        <input type="text" class="gui-input" id="uploader1" placeholder="no file selected" readonly>
                        <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></span>
                    </label>
                </div><!-- end  section -->
```

Your help and time is much appreciated. 
Sincerely,

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I would like to come to that point however I haven't done file uploads before. I have added the following to my smartprocess.php but file doesn't even uploaded to uploads/ folder. Forget about storing file name to Mysql

Comment: if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){ 
     $folder = "uploads/"; 
     $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
     $full_path = $folder.$file; 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) {

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_FILES` variable of php to help your files uploaded. There is a simple tutorial on file upload in php [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)